# Button to go through array one value at a time without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

I have a function that generates 10 random and unique numbers between 1-20.

```
function contain($prevItems, $number) {
            for ($k=0; $k<sizeof($prevItems); $k++) {
              if ($prevItems[$k] == $number)
                return true;
              }
              return false;
            }
            $num[0] = rand(1,20);
            $prevItems[0] = $num[0];
            for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) {
              $num[$i] = rand(1,10);
              while (contain($prevItems, $num[$i])) {
                $num[$i] = rand (1,20);
              }
              $prevItems[$i] = $num[$i];
           }
           sort($num);
```

I then have a button that fetches the first number from the array and echoes a text from database based on the number.

```
<form action="koe.php" method="POST">
<input id="myform" type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="new question">
</form

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if($result = $my->query("SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY OID DESC LIMIT 1")) {
    if($result = $my->query('SELECT * FROM questions WHERE OID="'.$prevItems[0].'"')) {
      while($t = $result->fetch_object()) {
         echo '<h2>'.$t->text.'</h2>';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is this: I want the button to echo the next value from the previously. Like I want to echo prevItems[1] and then prevItems[2] without the page refresh because at the moment every time I press the button, the page refreshes and the function makes new 10 numbers so they're not unique anymore.

I've tried to stop page refresh with javascript

```
    var frm = $('#myform');
frm.submit(function (ev) {
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            alert('ok');
        }
    });

    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

I figured it can't work like this though but I'm not sure how to fix it.

To clarify: My problem is to go through array on a button click without page refresh. Everytime a button is pressed, the next number from array would show up. array[0] -> array[1] -> array[2] -> array[3]

Comment: You have to do it with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your php page to expect a post variable "num"

```
if(isset($_POST['num'])) {
  if($result = $my->query("SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY OID DESC LIMIT     1")) {
    if($result = $my->query('SELECT * FROM questions WHERE     OID="'.$_POST['num'].'"')) {
      while($t = $result->fetch_object()) {
         echo '<h2>'.$t->text.'</h2>';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

//you probably want to google "mysql prevent injection" right after you get this working

Then in your ajax call you can pass in the "num"

```
$(function(){
  $("mybutton").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "myURL",
     data: { num:myNums[0] },
     success: function (data) {
            $("#output").innerHTML += data;
            myNums.splice(0,1); //take out the first num
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it echoes the first number (2) properly. (this is $num): Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 4 [2] => 5 [3] => 6 [4] => 8 [5] => 9 [6] => 10 [7] => 11 [8] => 13 [9] => 19 [10] => 20) but the problem is I need to echo array[1] the next time I press the button which is number (4) in this case. Then the next time I press the button it should go to array[2] which is (5)

Comment: I thought my code would do that...  It sends the first number as num (myNums[0]).. Then after it gets the response it takes the first number off the list, meaning, next time you hit the button it should send the next number.

Comment: The page refreshes every time I press the button which resets the array and starts from [0] again.

Comment: Did you keep your form as a form with an action?  You need to take that out or else it will redirect.

Comment: `<form method="POST">
        <input id="myform" type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Uusi kysymys">
      </form>`

Comment: I would delete the form tag all together, and add a button that calls the function with the ajax call in it

Comment: I'm being a pain at the moment but I'm not familiar with ajax.  `<button id="myform" class="btn btn-primary onclick="arrayajax();"/>new question</button>` 
`$(function arrayajax() {`  Is this correct

Comment: @Santona The button part looks good, the other part it looks like you're calling arrayajax() when it loads (the $(function thing happens when the page loads). . Instead try function arrayajax() { <the function code in my answer above> };

Comment: @Charley Wynn `<button id="myform" class="btn btn-primary onclick="arrayajax();"/>new question</button> <script>
 function arrayajax() {
$(function(){
  $("#myform").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "myURL",
     data: { num:myNums[0] },
     success: function (data) {
            $("#output").innerHTML += data;
            myNums.splice(0,1); //take out the first num
        }
    });
  });
});
};
</script> `  The button doesn't do anything atm.

Comment: inside your script tag, get rid of $(function() { $("#myform").on("click"),

as well as the closing })}) for those

Comment: Still does nothing unfortunately.